# Moment of Inertia of Water.

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotation, moment-of-inertia

> Determine the moment of inertia $\Theta$ of a water molecule ($m_H=m,m_O=M$) for a rotation around the axis which is perpendicular to the molecule plane and goes through the center of mass **S** of the molecule. Let the distances be $d(H~H)=2a$ and $d(O~H)=b$.

I practiced some exercises on moment of inertia and am already stuck on this one. 
My approach was to express the center of mass with the given distances 2a and b and from there to get the distance of each atom to the center of mass. Then I should be allowed to add all the inertia for the total inertia, correct?

But I'm struggling with even finding the center of mass. My first silly approach was to go for the general center of mass of a triangle, but since the mass in this case isn't evenly distributed I can't do that.

Anyone got a way to find the center of mass and from that the moment of inertia?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the center of mass of two point masses? And three point masses? See where this is going?

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagram you need is this:

[image]

Obviously, the horizontal position of the center of mass is centered between the two H atoms; the vertical position is the point where the molecule would balance.

So if the distance from the H-H line to S is h, and the mass of the atoms is $m_O$ and $m_H$, then balance happens when

$$2 m_H h = m_O (b-h)$$

From there you should be able to find $h$; then you can find the distance of each atom to the center of rotation, and the moment of intertia will be

$$I = \sum mr^2$$

over the three atoms.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Very easy explanation, but just to be sure: $h=\frac{m_Ob}{2m_H+m_O}$ and then I would use the pythagorean theorem to find $r_H$ and $r_O$?

Comment: @MigJakker - that looks correct, yes. And since you need the square of the distance, you don't have to take the square root first...